# TypeError: 'GoodsCategory' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, django

goods.py

```
    class Goods(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(GoodsCategory, verbose_name='xxx')
        goods_sn = models.CharField(default='', max_length=50, verbose_name='xxx')
        name = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='xxx')
        click_num = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='xxx')
        sold_num = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='xxx')
```

import_goods_data.py

```
from apps.goods.models import Goods, GoodsCategory, GoodsImage

from db_tools.data.product_data import row_data

for goods_detail in row_data:
    goods = Goods()
    goods.name = goods_detail['name']
    goods.market_price = float(int(goods_detail['market_price'].replace('￥', '').replace('&', '')))
    goods.shop_price = float(int(goods_detail['sale_price'].replace('&', '').replace('$', '')))
    goods.goods_brief = goods_detail['desc'] if goods_detail['desc'] is not None else ''
    goods_goods_desc = goods_detail['goods_desc'] if goods_detail['goods_desc'] is not None else ''
    goods.goods_front_image = goods_detail['images'][0] if goods_detail['images'] is not None else ''

    category_name = goods_detail['categorys'][-1]
    category = GoodsCategory.objects.filter(name=category_name)
    if category:
        goods.category = category[0]
    goods.save()
```

Because I got a error.So let me try to write it this way:

```
categories = GoodsCategory.objects.filter(name=category_name)
if categories.exists():
    category = categories[0]
else:
    category = GoodsCategory.objects.create(name=category_name)
goods.category = category[0]
goods.save()
```

But I had another error.
**TypeError: 'GoodsCategory' object does not support indexing**

Comment: Why are you still trying to index? `category` is a single item, there is no need to do `category[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to index the category object

In the if condition you already indexed the QuerySet and got the category object, in the else condition you are creating a new object using create, which will return an instance.

So try the following,

```
categories = GoodsCategory.objects.filter(name=category_name)  # You get a QuerySet here
if categories.exists():
    category = categories[0]  # Okay to index a QuerySet when something exists in it, you get the category object when you index it
else:
    category = GoodsCategory.objects.create(name=category_name)  # You get a GoodsCategory object here, cannot index this and no need to, since you already have the object
goods.category = category
goods.save()
```